# Como clonar un proyecto hecho angular desde Git y que me traiga todas sus carpetas

Tags: angular, git, github, git-push

[image: imagen]

Estoy iniciándome con el tema de Github y cuestión es estuve subiendo un proyecto que estoy desarrollando con un amigo en Angular y cuando hice los pasos en GIT haciendo "git add ." veo que la carpeta NODE MODULE no esta subida en el repositorio creado. 
Ahora cuando clono ese repositorio a mi PC tampoco lo veo, Como puedo hacer para generarme un pull de mi carpeta y que me aparezca mi proyecto completo.

Comment: Revisa si tienes un archivo .gitignore, en tu caso creo que es el que aparece sin nombre de la imagen, en ese archivo se incluyen los archivos y carpetas que ignorará.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La carpeta `node_modules` es generada por las dependencias de npm que ocupe tu proyecto, en terminal corre los siguientes comandos para ver si tienes instalados node y npm

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Si los tienes instalados, debes dirigirte a la carpeta raiz de tu proyecto y correr

```
npm install
```

Esto generará la carpeta

Comment: Si si el node lo tengo instalado y el npm no lo tenia. pero mi consulta es cuando subiis tu proyecto al git, subís también el node module no? porque pareciera q me subio todo los archivos menos la carpeta node module. como deberia hacer?

Comment: La carpeta `node_modules` suele tener un peso alto. Por lo que no se recomienda subir a git, si aun asi deseas subirlo revisa el archivo `.gitignore` como lo mencionó @Magotecnologia y si esta en lista, borralo y guarda cambios

Comment: ok! entonces mi compañero por ejemplo si quiere trabajar en una rama propia y descarga el proyecto no es necesario que descargue esa carpeta no?

Comment: No, tambien debe correr `npm install`

Comment: ahh perfecto, muchas gracias Jonathan